# Analyze a string of characters for (ABC)^n using stacks

Tags: java, string

I have a string of characters with As, Bs and Cs that I need to analyze for a Language (ABC)^n, where n>0. If this string is "ABCABCABC" it is true, if it is "ABAB" or "AB" it is not true.  I keep getting the error message string index out of bounds when it reads a line "AB" and then it stops the program.
Here is the code I have:

```
public boolean isABC(String line) throws StackException{
    MyStack Stack = new MyStack();

    // initialize loop counters
    int i = 0;
    int n = line.length();
    char ch = line.charAt(i);

    // Push all 'A's to L6Stack 
    while (i < line.length()){
        if(line.charAt(i) == 'A'){
            L6Stack.push(ch);
            i++;
            if(line.charAt(i)=='B'){
                L6Stack.push(ch);
                i++;
                if(line.charAt(i) =='C'){
                    L6Stack.push(ch);
                    i++;
                }else
                    break;
            }else
                break;
        }else
            break;
    }
    if (i == n ){
        return true; 
    }else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using regex?

Comment: Yes regex will be a good option for solving such problems........Why don't u use it????

Comment: What happens if first char not equals A?

Comment: You should learn to debug your code. There are several mistakes. First one is to access `line.charAt(i)` before going into the while loop. There might be no character at all, and the variable could even be `null`. Second one is to always read chunks of three characters without checking whether the string is long enough; thus the IOOBE.

Comment: if you passed AB first A so it will do i++ second B so it will do i++ next there is nothing still you trying to read charAt(i) for C so index out of bound execption

Comment: I am guessing this is an exercise. No other reason to think of recognizing ABC and using stacks...

Comment: Additionally, the language (ABC)^n is a regular language. You should really use a state machine or a regular expression for recognizing that. Stacks are for recognizing context free languages.

Comment: Not sure what regex is, but I don't think we are allowed to use it

Comment: To translate @Seelenvirtuose into less technical terms - if there is no nesting, you do not need stacks.

Comment: Any suggestions on learning to debug code because I know I need to work on it

Comment: A regex-based answer: `return line.matches("(ABC)*");` -- probably not what the teacher intended.

Comment: oh no, that would be too easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code tries to advance 3 characters before checking if it can do so without overstepping the bounds. You can fix it by replacing all `i++` with `if (i==n) return false; i++`. However, you can also rewrite it all to be a *lot* cleaner:

Try this:

```
public boolean isABC(String line) {
  int total = line.length();
  int position = 0;
  char prev = 'C';
  while (position < total) {
      char c = line.get(position++);
      switch (c) {
          case 'A': if (prev != 'C') return false; break;
          case 'B': if (prev != 'A') return false; break;
          case 'C': if (prev != 'B') return false; break;
      }
      prev = c;
  }
  return prev == 'C';
}
```

You could also add them all into a stack and then `pop()` the stack (so `char c = stack.pop()`, reversing the logic), but it is really not necessary for this particular expression.

---

Edit: added stack-based variant:

```
public boolean isABC(String line) {
  // fill stack
  Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
  for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++) {
      stack.push(line[i]);
  }

  // reverse operations while popping from stack
  char prev = 'A';
  while ( ! stack.isEmpty()) {
      char c = stack.pop();
      switch (c) {
          case 'A': if (prev != 'B') return false; break;
          case 'B': if (prev != 'C') return false; break;
          case 'C': if (prev != 'A') return false; break;
      }
      prev = c;
  }
  return prev == 'A';
}
```

Comment: We have to use stacks is why. :-(

Comment: Added a stack-based variant. It is essentially the same thing, but now you look at the characters starting from the end instead of the beginning. The first loop is used to fill the stack.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the string length is two ("AB") then when you get to

```
if(line.charAt(i) =='C')
```

the value of `i` will be `2`. A string of length two has characters at positions `0` and `1` only. If you use `charAt(2)` you are trying to read beyond the end of the string, resulting in the exception.

Right now you will get an error whenever the input string length is not a multiple of 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to correct your logic but I will try to explain why you are getting SIOOB Exception. See inline comments.

Let's say 
line = "AB";
so `length = 2` 
and `i = 0`

```
while (i < line.length()){//this condition returns true.
        if(line.charAt(i) == 'A'){// you are trying to access 0th Element.
            L6Stack.push(ch);
            i++;// i is 1 now.
            if(line.charAt(i)=='B'){// trying to access 1st element.
                L6Stack.push(ch);
                i++;//i is 2 now.
                if(line.charAt(i) =='C'){// trying to access 2st element. which would give you exception because there is no 2nd element.
                    L6Stack.push(ch);
                    i++;
                }else
                    break;
            }else
                break;
        }else
            break;
    }
```